# pulsating blue circle and dot in mapkit - iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone

How can I add the "Pulsating blue circle" in my gps application. 
Currently i am fetching my current location by CCLocationManager.

I am using mapView.showsUserLocation = True, but this only display a pin at my current location.

How can i get that "blue circle" as in the default maps app.

update: many app does this. for example - Realtor.com

Thanks

Comment: When I set showsUserLocation to YES for a map view it shows the blue dot and does tracking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Implement the delegate method:

`- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv viewForAnnotation: (id<MKAnnotation>)annotation`

and return nil if `if (annotation == mv.userLocation)`. This tell the `MKMapView` to use whatever standard annotation it deems appropriate.

Comment: Thank You! Thank You! Thank You! .... its working .. but having a little problem.. it does not pulsating after a while .. as in the default maps app.

Comment: Not sure about that...are you running on the simulator? Perhaps if you try on the device.

Comment: i know this was answered a while ago, but to any one woundering why the blue dot stops pulsating.... this is because your location has been deteremied to the level of accuracy you specified.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (annotation == Current Location){
return nil;

}else{

}
```

Comment: I already got my question's answer long ago.. and thats the same you posted today!! :)